# Roslyn: Check if method parameter can not be null

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Using Roslyn, my aim is to check if a method parameter is checked for not being null before the parameter is dereferenced. This check can be in a submethod of course.

My approach is to get the first dereferencing of the parameter and search the syntax tree between that and the method start for null checks. How can I do some kind of control flow analysis to determine if the first dereferencing of the parameter can be reached with the parameter being null?

Answer (score 1):

This is way too broad question, with a little explanation what is your final goal. Are you trying to detect null-pointer exceptions before they even happen, 100%? (Pretty much impossible)

I have written static analysis myself few months ago, I didn't use roslyn, but this doesn't matter.

Check this out to get you possibly started - it's reporting warnings when there are unused variables:

```
internal class UnUsedVariableWarningDefinition : ICodeIssue
{
    public IEnumerable<IssueReport> Analyze()
    {
        var usageMap = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        var variableMap = new Dictionary<string, IdentifierNode>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        foreach (var node in NodeAnalyzerHelper.FindNodesDfs(Root))
        {
            var assignmentNode = node as AssignmentNode;
            if (assignmentNode != null)
            {
                var variableNode = assignmentNode.Identifier;

                int usages;
                if (!usageMap.TryGetValue(variableNode.Identifier, out usages))
                {
                    usageMap[variableNode.Identifier] = 0;
                    variableMap[variableNode.Identifier] = variableNode;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // not really an assignmentNode,
                // let's see if we have detected the usage of IdentifierNode somewhere.
                var variableNode = node as IdentifierNode;
                if (variableNode != null)
                {
                    if (usageMap.ContainsKey(variableNode.Identifier))
                        usageMap[variableNode.Identifier]++;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var node in usageMap.Where(x => x.Value == 0).Select(x => variableMap[x.Key]))
        {
            yield return node.ConstructWarning("No usages of this variable found. Are you sure this is needed?");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `FindNodesDfs()` is basically a syntax tree walker, which walks syntax nodes depth-first style. What it does is just scans AssigfnmentNodes and puts them to Dictionary, as soon as it identifies IdentifierNode, it checks the dictionary if it has previously encountered assignment, or not. It's a bit similiar what you're trying to do, I guess.